# Key is showing Promise as a value after firing ractive.set

Tags: javascript, json, ractivejs

I'm trying to change the values inside the a JSON object using ractive.on and ractive.set. Basically it will get the values inside the input element(with ractive variables) and assign them to there respective keys after pressing the anchor element with a `on-click` event. Instead of showing the proper values it shows `Promise` instead. I have attach an image for reference.

https://jsfiddle.net/clestcruz/L38tsud7/

[image]

```
<body>

  <div id='container'></div>

  <script id='template' type='text/ractive'>

      <p>Provide the company information for the:</p>

      <label>Company Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-text full-width" placeholder="Enter the company name" id="accountName" value="{{leadData.accountName}}"/>



      <label>Street Name.</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-text" placeholder="-" id="streetName" value="{{leadData.streetName}}"/>

      <a class="button cta" on-click="addLead">Create Account</a>


  </script>

  <script src='http://cdn.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive.min.js'></script>

  <script>

      var app = new Ractive({
        el       : '#container',
        template : '#template',
    });

     var data = {
        'accountName'   : app.get('leadData.accountName'),
        'streetName'    : app.get('leadData.streetName'),
     }


      app.on('addLead', function(event) {
         var data = {
           'accountName'   : app.set('leadData.accountName'),
           'streetName'    : app.set('leadData.streetName'),
         }
         console.log(data);
      });

  </script>


</body>
```

Comment: I don't have experience with Ractive, but if you want to get data shouldn't you call `app.get('leadData...)` instead of `app.set` in `app.on('addLead)`?

Comment: Its actually ractive not reactive

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the typo. Anyway, make sense for me that setting a value is a Promise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably mean is `app.get` and not `app.set`. In addition, event handlers execute in the context of the instance. That means you do not require a reference to the instance with an external variable (in this case, `app`). You can simply use `this`.

```
app.on('addLead', function(event) {
  var data = {
    accountName: this.get('leadData.accountName'),
    streetName: this.get('leadData.streetName'),
  }
  // Do other stuff with data
});
```